# Simultaneous use of Hibernate and Spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

Is it possible to use Spring Data JPA (backed by Hibernate as JPA provider) and directly use Hibernate at the same time?

The problem is that when i use JpaTransactionManager, i'm not able to retrieve current session with `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`. When i switch to HibernateTransaction manager, JPA repositories are not able to commit changes.

Here is the part of my Spring context (with that context i'm not able to use direct Hibernate calls):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/IPGCONF"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.satgate"/>
```

Example of hibernate repository:

```
public Collection<Layer> listCurrent(Carrier carrier) {
    Criteria query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                    .createCriteria(Layer.class)
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("carrier", carrier));
    query.createCriteria("bitrate")
            .addOrder(Order.desc("bitrate"))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("symbolrate", carrier.getSymbolrate()));
    return query.list();
}
```

Example of Spring data repository definition:

```
public interface BitrateRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Bitrate, Long> { }
```

Software versions:

```
<org.springframework.version>4.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
<org.springframework.data.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.data.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.0.Final</hibernate.version>
```

So, the question is - is it possible to use in the same transaction (specified by @Transactional annotation) both Spring JPA repositories and direct Hibernate calls and how to achieve that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of creating a SessionFactory, use `EntityManager.unwrap(Session.class)` to get a Hibernate Session and retrieve the session factory from the Session object.

You can also use `EntityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)` to get the Hibernate SessionFactory directly.

Comment: It would be slightly more helpful if you'd include the package. There are billions of packages in Spring and Eclipse does not find an EntityManager by itself...

Comment: For that you need JPA javax.persistence.EntityManager

Answer (score 25):

You need a single way of configuration you are now configuring both Hibernate and JPA. You should be using JPA for configuration so remove the hibernate setup.

You are using Hibernate4 so you can take advantage of the, not so well known, `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` of Spring. If you need access to the `SessionFactory` (which I assume you need).

When applied your configuration will like something like this.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I would suggest to only use this as an intermediate solution while you are refactoring your applicaiton to use the plain JPA api. I wouldn't suggest mixing both strategies.

Comment: That's way better than what we currently recommend in our [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/faq.html#d0e2924). Would you mind creating a ticket to improve the docs on that? Wouldn't mind a pull request either :).

Comment: @OliverGierke [Done](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-462) & [Done](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/pull/57).

Comment: @M.Deinum I confirmed it's not well known but very elegant! one question though (curiosity) : why wouldn't you mix both strategies ?

Comment: Mixing 2 different ORM strategies can be confusing, better to stick to a single approach imho.

Comment: One additional note: this approach requires an additional JPA property due `No CurrentSessionContext configured!` (explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28852407/525238)

Comment: FYI, `HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean` has been deprecated since Spring FWK 4.3. See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.3.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.html).

Comment: @GuillaumeHusta did you find any alterate solution ?

Comment: There's a solution in the javadoc. It simply uses  `EntityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class)`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did, and it worked well:
**one data source, two transaction manager.**
Data source bean:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <!-- bulabula... -->
</bean>
```

For Hibernate XML based configuration:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="#{propertyUtils.getList('hibernate.hbm')}"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            <!-- bulabulabula... -->
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" primary="true" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And for spring-data-jpa java based configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.sharder.core.repository"}, 
transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(ComboPooledDataSource comboPooledDataSource) {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("org.sharder.core.entity");
    factory.setDataSource(comboPooledDataSource);
    factory.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return factory;
}

@Bean(name = "jpaTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "true");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", "20");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
    return properties;
}
```

}

Notice that, `transactionManagerRef = "jpaTransactionManager"` set the JpaTransactionManager to be used with the repositories.
[Spring Data JPA namespace attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.repositories)

Comment: Now that a few months have passed, would you still recommend using dual transaction managers?  I have the same problem; I want to use Spring JPA on top of legacy Hibernate code.

Comment: @krislarson If you want to upgrade an old project to the latest architecture project, I think it is ok. Because this can phase out the old code ;)

Comment: ...which is exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks