# Can HibernateTemplate coexist with EntityManager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have a spring 3 application that still uses the deprecated `HibernateTemplate` for persistence and want to migrate to the more modern JPA `EntityManager`.

Is it possible to use both APIs in parallel during the migration (possibly even both in a single transaction), so that we can do the migration in small steps?

Or will we have to do it big bang?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, why not.

The easiest would be to drop your `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and `HibernateTransactionManager` configuration and replace it with `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and `JpaTransactionManager`, respectively.

Then to obtain a `SessionFactory` add the [`HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean.html), which exposes the underlying `SessionFactory` for the `EntityManagerFactory`.

This way both technologies should peacefully coexist.

There are some reports that doing this leads to a an exception stating `No CurrentSessionContext configured!`. If you get it add the following to either your `persistence.xml`

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext"/>
```

or `jpaProperties` of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
    <props>
        <prop name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
    <props>
<property>
```

Comment: Now I get the error "No CurrentSessionContext configured!"

Comment: Solved, now I get the next error: "createCriteria is not valid without active transaction". Seems like my @Transactional annotations are not processed any more

Comment: More details: There is a transactionInterceptor, there is a JdbcTransaction, but the transaction's localStatus is 'NOT_ACTIVE'.

Comment: Why do you need a transactionintereptor? I don't see that. Without seeing your current configuration it is hard to tell (also see my extended answer).

Comment: thanks it works now! Using hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext did the trick

Comment: It seemed to work but actually the transaction management is still messed up. It seems that hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext works only inside J2EE containers with a JTA provider.

Comment: It shouldn't work in JTA environment for that there is a special subclass the `SpringJtaSessionContext`. Make sure that you don't have multiple transaction managers. Also are you using JTA or not?

Comment: I'm not using JTA, and I'm sure I don't have multiple TX managers. SpringSessionContext uses ConfigurableJtaPlatform.jtaPlatformClass.getMethod("retrieveTransactionManager") for looking up the tx manager, but this works only in a JTA environment. So the tx manager in SpringSessionContext is null for me.

Comment: No it doesn't. in a non JTA environment it return a default noop implementation (the `NoJtaPlatform` implementation to be more specific). The lookup is needed so that it would work in a JTA environment but that doesn't automatically mean it works only in a JTA environment. Apparently it wants a thread bound session, you could try and add the `HibernateTransactionManager` and specify in the `@Transactional` annotation which tx manager to use. This will work until you need both the `Session` and `EntityManager` to be available.

Comment: My Solution is now to use `((HibernateEntityManager)entityManager).getSession()` instead of `@Autowired SessionFactory`. This works without additional XML configuration hazzle.

Comment: Juste be careful about the version of Hibernate and Spring see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206837/hhh000302-unable-to-construct-current-session-context-org-springframework-orm

Comment: Hi @BastianVoigt! I ran into the very same problem (tx management not working if exposed SessionFactory is used). Your solution (using `((HibernateEntityManager)entityManager).getSession()` instead) seems to work at first glance. Have you experienced any unwanted side effects over the time? Thanks!

Comment: No, can't remember any problems. It was a temporary solution only for making the migration to JPA easier anyway, so we didn't use it for a long time

Comment: Old thread but... I am modernizing part of an old spring app (plain hibernate to JPA) and hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext was the key. Thanks!